# .awaitMessageComponent() not receiving select menu interaction

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js

**EDIT**: Fixed the code as per waki285's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76966061/4421671). The problem still persists.

As per the [discord.js guide on component interactions](https://discordjs.guide/message-components/interactions.html), I've been trying to get my select menu to work using an `.awaitMessageComponent()` call on the interaction reply. This is my code:

```js
const selectMenu = new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
    .setCustomId("roleselect")
    .setPlaceholder("Select your role!")
    .addOptions(
        { label: "role1", value: "role1" },
        { label: "role2", value: "role2" }
    );

const prompt = await this.interaction.reply({
    content: "Please select your role!",
    ephemeral: true,
    components: [
        new ActionRowBuilder<StringSelectMenuBuilder>().addComponents(
            selectMenu
        ),
    ],
});

const menuInteraction = await prompt.awaitMessageComponent({
    filter: (interaction) =>
        interaction.user.id === this.interaction.user.id,
    time: 600 * 1000,
    componentType: ComponentType.StringSelect,
});

const selectedRoleValue = menuInteraction.values[0];
```

The select menu renders just fine:

[image]

But after choosing an option, the interaction fails and the bot never gets to the `selectedRoleValue` assignment line:

[image]

The interaction IS being picked up by my `client.on("interactionCreate", ...)` code (where it is logged and ignored), but it is not picked up by the `prompt.awaitMessageComponent()` code. I tried the equivalent code but with a [component collector](https://discordjs.guide/message-components/interactions.html#component-collectors) instead and that code also didn't pick up any interactions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I am unsure why this is an issue, but the issue lied with the fact that I was using `this.interaction.reply()`. For some reason, the `awaitMessageComponent()` was not listening for any more interactions after that, even though that's how it's written in the [documentation](https://discordjs.guide/message-components/interactions.html#awaiting-components).

I updated it so that it instead uses `this.interaction.followUp()` (and made sure that somewhere earlier to that, I ran `this.interaction.deferReply()`). This worked.

[waki285's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76966061/4421671) did point out a valid issue in the first version of the code though, which was that my filter was originally

```js
interaction.user.id === this.interaction.id
```

instead of

```js
interaction.user.id === this.interaction.user.id
```

which would have also caused it to fail.

Answer (score 2):

`this.interaction.id` is NOT interacted user id but id used to handle interactions internally.

So try this code:

```
const menuInteraction = await prompt.awaitMessageComponent({
    filter: (interaction) =>
        interaction.user.id === this.interaction.user.id,
    time: 600 * 1000,
    componentType: ComponentType.StringSelect,
});
```

Comment: This was a good catch thank you! I've fixed it but unfortunately it still didn't solve the problem. The behaviour is exactly the same.

Truth be told, I expected that it wouldn't fix the problem since I had already tried running `awaitMessageComponent()` with no options (i.e. no `filter`, `time`, or `componentType`) and it still failed. So I don't think the filtering I'm doing is causing the `awaitMessageComponent()` to ignore the interaction.